# Docker SCRATCH container can't find files

Tags: docker, redis, static-linking, dockerfile

I have a very simple dockerfile:

```
FROM scratch
MAINTAINER "aosmith" <a..h@...com>
EXPOSE 6379
ADD redis-server /redis-server
ENTRYPOINT ["/redis-server"]
```

The docker file is in a folder with a statically compiled copy of redis-server.

The build runs find but the container refuses to start:

```
➜  redis git:(master) ✗ docker run f16
no such file or directory
Error response from daemon: Cannot start container 46be4ed97560cd63fa4f639bed0e25358e807a8229bb3b5a613aa1274e037040: [8] System error: no such file or directory
```

I've tried various combinations of `CMD` `EXEC` `ADD` and `COPY` with no luck.

I'm building redis from source like this:

```
make CFLAGS="-static" EXEEXT="-static" \
MALLOC=libc LDFLAGS="-I/usr/local/include/"
```

Worth noting I use basically the exact same Dockerfile for go projects without any problems.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The "scatch" image is literally empty and can only be used by technologies like go which have near zero dependencies on it's runtime environment.

Try a base image that supplies a set of OS utilities, like bash, etc.  For example

```
FROM ubuntu
MAINTAINER "aosmith" <a..h@...com>
EXPOSE 6379
ADD redis-server /redis-server
ENTRYPOINT ["/redis-server"]
```

Comment: I get the idea that scratch depends on nothing, that's why I'm doing static compilation.  This image is going to be several hundred megs whereas the scratch image is only ~20mb.

Comment: Be careful of over optimization. Docker is a layered file system, the base image will only be downloaded once, no matter how many containers use it. It's why "ubuntu" is not always a bad choice (used by lots of projects). There are smaller base images (eg busybox, or alpine) that give you a bare minimum environment that just as valid a choice. In conclusion "scratch" is only suitable for technologies that truly have zero dependencies. Very few script languages easily fall into this category (Go being an obvious exception).

Comment: @Mark-OConnor I'd only try this with go or c/c++.

Comment: @AlexSmith Understood, but clearly the redis launch is looking for a file that it expects to exist on the target environement. Your next job will be to look thru the source code for this reference. You could also look at what base containers the Redis guys themselves are using.

Comment: Ah I should have included this... the docker run fails because it can't find the entrypoint:
`no such file or directory
Error response from daemon: Cannot start container d70e6f0fbc9965cf8c09c8c61d8e116c7e8b7ea9ee441783020acd297bbfc597: [8] System error: no such file or directory`